# elasticsearch php client search query returns all documents

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've been trying to search using 'match' and 'fuzzy', but I keep getting all of the documents, whether they match or not.

I've tried these 3 incarnations of my search:

1.

```
$params = [
                'index' => 'my_engine',
                'type' => 'my_type',
                'body' => [
                        'query' => [
                                'fuzzy' => [
                                        '_all' => $keyword
                                ]
                        ]
                ]
        ];
```

2. ```
   $params = [
           'index' => 'my_engine',
           'type' => 'my_type',
           'body' => [
                   'query' => [
                           'match' => [
                                   'title' => 'members'
                           ]
                   ]
           ]
   ];
   ```
3. ```
   $params['index'] = 'my_engine';
   $params['type'] = 'my_type';
   $params['body']['query']['match']['title'] = 'members';
   ```

Did I miss something during indexing?
I didn't provide any mapping.

Comment: How are you sending your query?

Comment: I find that  this works :  $json = '{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "_all" : "'.$keyword.'"
              
        }
    }
}';  I am sending using the Elasticsearch PHP client.

Comment: The PHP Array way of doing things doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you also show the PHP code that sends your query?